# Cauchy's integral polynomial roots

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have $A(z)$ as the polynomial where none of its roots lie on the contour $\gamma$, how do we show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{A'(z)}{A(z)}\,dz=N, $$
where $N$ is the number of roots of $A(z)$ in $\gamma$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A(z)= (z-\alpha_1)...(z-\alpha_n)$, then you get $A'(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^n \prod_{i\neq j}}(z-\alpha_j)$.

So $\dfrac{A'(z)}{A(z)}= \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n}\frac{1}{z-\alpha_i}.$

Then you use the residue theorem to compute your integral, or you do it by hand, but the main point to notice is that 
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-\alpha_i}=0$$
if $\alpha_i$ is not in the region bounded by $\gamma.$

Comment: I edited your post slightly for readability and continuity. I hope you don't mind.